# How to fix java.lang.RuntimeException on windows for Android Stuido?

Tags: java, android, windows, android-studio, java-11

I can't seem to find a recent discussion on this issue. When starting android studio on windows I get the following error:

```
"java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not find installation home path. Please make sure bin/idea.properties is present in the installation directory."
```

I have the latest Java JDK installed (jdk-11.0.14) and have placed the path in the JAVA_HOME environment variable.

Comment: Try running it as administrator.

Comment: No, that did not fix the error. I still cannot open